# Timezone of a Shopware 6 setup

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I would like to know the timezone of a hosted Shopware 6. Is there anyway to retrieve that information through the admin api?

Comment: Why do you care? Which problem are you facing?

Comment: Actually I have developed a Shopware app that add features around the customers. These customers can input their birthdate. The system behind the app is detecting the birthday regarding the timezone of the "setup" that we call a "project". So when the merchant setup the app I need to retrieve a timezone to save to information into this "project"...

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

The Database Server of a shopware shop should be configured to be in UTC, but you can change the timezone for each user. So you need to know for which user you want to get the timezone information.